# IP Address and Layer 2

Tags: ipv4, switching, mac-address, ip-address, layer2

As per my Knowledge MAC address is required to communicate two machines...and on layer 2 (Switch) can't understand IP (if i am right)....suppose we have 2 systems (Sys1 and Sys2) with 2 different IP network (ex. 10.0.0.1 & 172.16.0.1) directly connected with layer 2 switch.
 No doubt there is no communication between sys1 and sys2. BUT WHY...?
If switch only read mac address of source and destination for communication then why systems of 2 different network not able to communicate.

what is the reason behind non communication...?
Are switches works on IPs also...?
in above example why not switch just read the MAC address of System and send packet to system 2...why in that case IPs are comes to play..?

Thanks for ur Replies.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Rajan,

It depends what you mean by "communicate."  The switch will forward packets based on MAC address only.  In that sense they will communicate.

But there are many other things that have to happen for the two devices to transfer data.

The sender needs to know the MAC address of sys2.  And when the receiver (sys2) replies, it also must know the MAC address of sys1. The devices will use the ARP protocol to learn MAC addresses.

ARP will only work if each device knows which interface to use.  That in turn requires that there is information in the device route table for that subnet.

Finally, the destination IP address has to match the IP of the receiver.  Otherwise the receiver will discard the packet.

Answer (score 0):

When a host goes to send a packet it first looks in it's routing table.

From the routing table it determines what interface to send the packet out on and the "next hop IP address".

You haven't said what the subnet masks are on your host, lets assume they are both 255.255.255.0.

Normally when sys1 tries to send a packet to sys2 it looks up the IP in it's routing table and decides to send it to it's default gateway. It then looks up the default gateway in it's ARP table (and makes an ARP request if needed). It doesn't try to do an arp request for sys2's IP address because it considers it to be out of network.

At least on linux this behaviour can be overridden with explicit routing table entries. I don't know about other systems.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my Knowledge MAC address is required to communicate two
>   machines...

That is only true for the IEEE LAN protocols that use MAC addressing. There are other layer-2 protocols that use other or no addressing.

> and on layer 2 (Switch) can't understand IP (if i am right)...

Layer-2 switches use layer-2 addresses. They do not strip off the layer-2 frame to look at the layer-3 packet. A layer-2 switch will not know if the layer-2 frame payload contains IPv4, IPX, IPv6, etc.

> suppose we have 2 systems (Sys1 and Sys2) with 2 different IP network
>   (ex. 10.0.0.1 & 172.16.0.1) directly connected with layer 2 switch. No
>   doubt there is no communication between sys1 and sys2. BUT WHY...?

It is because of the layer-2 address placed on the layer-2 frame encapsulating the layer-3 packet. A source host will mask both its own layer-3 address and the destination layer-3 address with its configured network mask to see if they are on the same layer-3 network. If they are on the same layer-3 network, then the source host will use the layer-2 address of the destination host for the destination address on the layer-2 frame. If the destination host is on a different layer-3 network, the source host will use the layer-2 address of its configured gateway as the layer-2 destination address on the layer-2 frame.

> If switch only read mac address of source and destination for
>   communication then why systems of 2 different network not able to
>   communicate.

As explained above, the layer-2 switch will use the layer-2 address to deliver the frame, but if the destination host is on a different layer-3 network, the layer-2 address on the layer-2 frame will not be the destination host, it will be the layer-2 address of the source host's configured gateway.

> what is the reason behind non communication...?

I explained it above.

> Are switches works on IPs also...?

No.

> in above example why not switch just read the MAC address of System
>   and send packet to system 2...why in that case IPs are comes to
>   play..?

The source host is the device that addresses both the layer-2 frames and the layer-3 packets, and it will not address the layer-2 frame with the destination host layer-2 address if the destination host is on a different layer-3 network.

Answer (score -4):

Assume there are machines M1-172.31.1.10 and M2-10.10.1.10 connected in switch and trying to ping M2 from M1

- when I put command ***"ping 10.10.1.10"***
  Output was "unkoun Network/Undefined network" cause the system have routing knowledge of 172.31.1.0/24 network not about 10.10.1.10 so we have to made routing table entry by adding command ***"route add -net 10.10.1.0/24 gw 172.31.1.10"*** which will tell IP and Data-link layer stack where to or on which port this packet need to be forward.
- Now Ping again ***"ping 10.10.1.10"*** This time error will be different ***"Destination Host Unreachable"*** we encouter this error because when we try to ***ping first packet generated will be ARP*** for IP adress to MAC adress maping. when ARP reply gets generated to broadcast packet from M2 machine its has no routing info where to route this packet so follow same procedure on M2
- On M2 do execute following command ***"route add -net 172.31.1.0/24 gw 10.10.1.10"***.
  Now try to ping from M1 to M2 I Hope You will be able to route the packet.